# Multipartitioning Spring Batch implementation in GAE environment

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-batch

I am completely new to both Spring batch and Google App engine. Our requirement is to add a Spring batch into a java web application and trigger it through a REST service in the web application deployed in Google App engine.

The Spring Batch processes a very large csv file in multipartitioning mode. We have implemented the Batch and it works perfectly when run from Eclipse. But when it is triggered in GAE we are stuck with the below issue. I am searing in google/stackoverflow for a while but not able to find the resolution.

```
[INFO] INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=greenButtonBatch]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
[INFO] org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[greenButtonBatch]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:120)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
[INFO]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
[INFO]  at com.controller.BatchJobExecutionController.home(BatchJobExecutionController.java:50)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
```